# Running a webserver with a portable local webserver

Tags: web-applications, webserver

We are developing a webapp that requires a local web server. The problem is, we can't install anything on their machine for some reasons. Is there any alternative for this one?

Comment: Do you mean something like XAMPP ?

Comment: What do you mean with "ANYTHING"? Does it mean something that opens a socket to the world? Does it mean you cannot install any executable file? In the first case, Apache (or any other web server) can allow connections only from localhost. In the second case, if no executable is allowed I can't figure out how can you run the webapp! (unless they already have a web server installed)

Comment: What are the requirements? What operating system? What platform is the webapp based on - PHP, ...?

Comment: Something similar to XAMPP but doesn't require installation. These are the applications that might work for the project: https://code.google.com/p/mongoose/ and http://zwamp.sourceforge.net/

Note: I'm using Chromium Embedded Framework to run the application which is needed to handle multiple screens at the same time. :)

So, the point here is to run both webserver and app at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are just searching a running http webserver which doesn't need to be extendable, if not the following won't apply for you.

If there is Java installed on that machine you can use one of the many "single-file-webservers" that are out there.
For example: https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd

Or: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/

If you have Node.js running you will find even more, very simply and efficient solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I think Nancy can do the trick for you.

[Nancy](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy)